# How do I get a payload inside the java method while making a POST request to spring-boot?

Tags: spring-boot, post

I would like to see what the POST request has, however, I do not want to do it in the method header but using the java code in the method body. Instead of failing the method, I would like to return some value (like when using try-catch) if the POST request is a null.

Comment: use if/else !!?

Comment: Use if else to see what the POST request has.  Good one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how it could be done in Spring:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/some-path")
public class YourController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/further path")    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public YourReturnObject postMethod(@RequestBody DataYouWant dataYouWant) {
        // Basically, dataYouWant is the request body
    }
}
```

If you don't have a strict `@RequestBody` format, you could simply use `Map<String, ?>` to get your json value into a `Map` instead of a `DataYouWant` object. And obviously `YourReturnObject` is the object you want to return as the response body to be serialised as json.

Comment: I've tried the Map<String, ?> but it didn't work, the problem is the front-end I am using with Spring Boot, so I had to pass everything as URL string.  I will accept your answer because it is what I asked for.

Comment: What is the frontend? Maybe I could help with it. This is how you access your request body, so it should be the frontend. Passing everything as query params might not be healthy.

Comment: Just react.js with the axios making a POST request. I have to set it as 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  because nothing else works. Checked it with a PostMan, and it worked ... therefore it is the front-end fault.  PS Thank you.